# QTP - How to verify that an image object exists at a specific place in a WebTable?

Tags: qtp

I'm trying to verify if a specific image object is present in a specific cell of a web table. The object may or may not be present. There could be more image objects in same cell.

Can I use `GetCellData()` to get image object?
Secondly, after getting the details how can I confirm the object is same as the one I was looking for?

Comment: you should add more information to your question. What is the structure of that webTable and how are you trying to approach the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetCellData` is not a good tool for this scenario. You should use `ChildItem` instead, this returns the test object in the cell (rather than the text of the cell).

```
 Set table = Browser("B").Page("P").WebTable("T")
 imageCount = table.ChildItemCount(row, column, "Image")
 For i = 0 to imageCount -1
     Set img = table.ChildItem(row, column, "Image", i)
     if (img.GetROProperty("src") = expectedSrc) Then
         MsgBox "Found it!"
     End If
 Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Use Insight Object to verify Image.You just have to save that image in OR by using 'Add Insight Object' feature of OR.And at run time you can check the existence of this Insight Object.
Qtp will compare this Insight Object in OR with the one that is in application at Run Time